# script for automating insert scale bar, text, north arrow

Tags: python, arcmap

I've always wanted an automatic process for these tools instead of having to click insert again and again. It seems easy but I can't do it in modelbuilder and I can't seem to find anyone making a script for it on the web. I want to use a certain north arrow and scale bar each time.

Comment: I agree this would be a pretty cool add-in. One click and it adds 'em all.

Comment: This does sound like a good candidate for a Add-In. I used to do something like this years ago with VBA - all of the items you need should be accessible via ArcObjects.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into setting up a [map template](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002w000000.htm) with your prefered map elements?  It may be a good workaround for you in the short term.

Comment: I used to do it that way but it is only good for new projects

Comment: thanks, yea its good if you use map templates, but atm I don't use the same style maps. Damn I really thought there could be an easy way to do it.